# My while loop for the Fibonacci sequence is not terminating

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the sum of all even numbers less than 4,000,000. I believe I did my code correctly but I am not sure why it is not terminating.

```cpp
int main () {
    vector<int> fib {0,1};
    int fn;
    int n=0;
    int sum=0;

    while(sum <= 4000000000){
        fn = fib[n + 1] + fib[n];
        fib.push_back(fn);
        cout << fib[n + 2] << " ";
        n++;
            
        if(fib[n+2]%2==0){
            sum=sum+fib[n+2];
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

Here is my logic (please correct me where I am wrong):

- I initialized the first 2 values for the fibonnaci sequence.
- I initialized `n` and then created a recursive formula in the `while` loop so that it continues (`n++`) until the sum of the even numbers gets becomes greater than 4,000,000, in which case it should terminate.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? Are you aware of the range `int` can store?

Comment: You print `fib[n+2]` then you bump `n`.  At that point `fib[n+2]` points beyond the end of the vector.

Comment: Note: `int` often overflows at  2.2 billion, long before it will reach 4 billion

Comment: Beside which, by that point your vector will be 16GB long.  Remember, you don't NEED to save all of the elements.  All you need are the current and the previous values.

Comment: ^!!! One of the first rules of computer programming is "Don't store anything unless you have to."

Comment: Here is your code with a higher level of diagnostics enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/hfa9zhY7r  . It takes a while to learn to read this mess, but it's pretty much mandatory learning. `-Wall` and `-Wextra` turn on extra compiler warnings. Warnings mean the code is syntactically correct and can be transformed into a run-able program, but probably has logic errors. `-g` means preserve debugging information. `-O3` turns the optimizer way up. The more optimixzation you ask for, the closer the compielr looks at your code and the more mistakes it can spot.

Comment: `-fsanitize=address,undefined` adds extra runtime tests for logic mistakes, like running off the end of a buffer. The extra warnings point out `warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type` for `while(sum <= 4000000000)` saying that `sum` isn't big enough to reach 4000000000. The sanitizer output is  too lonmng to reallu cover here, but the important bits are `heap-buffer-overflow`, program reached outside valid memory, and the call stack showing where the buffer overflowed: `main /app/example.cpp:15`, or `cout << fib[n + 2] << " ";`. `n + 2` is too big for `fib`.

Comment: you only need the previous 2 terms not a whole vector

Answer (score 1):

```
if(fib[n+2]%2==0)
```

In the first iteration of your loop, here `n + 2` will be equal `fib.size()` which is an index that is *out of bounds*.

That leads to *undefined behavior*.

You should do this *before* you increase `n`.

Also note that you increase `n` ***twice*** in the loop. So every iteration the index will become further and further out of bounds of the vector.